# npm install for vite package gives syntax error in esbuild install.js

Tags: npm-install, vite, esbuild

I am trying to install packages on VScode (npm install) with the goal of using vite and svelte and get the error messages:

```
>esbuild@0.17.12 postinstall C:\Users\smurf\Data Visualisation\javascript\datavis-main\node_modules\esbuild
> node install.js
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
> at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
> at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
> at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
> at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
> at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
> at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

followed by many npm WARN messages and ending with:

```
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! esbuild@0.17.12 postinstall: `node install.js`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the esbuild@0.17.12 postinstall script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I am new to javascript so my apologies if the solution is trivial.

I tried to install esbuild manually or esbuild seperatly (npm install esbuild) but since I am new to javascript I do not know how to navigate this further.